# Does the diiodide(1−) anion exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions

With respect to chemical bonding does the $\ce{I2-}$ ion exist?

Comment: Probably not, is assume that the equilibrium is entirely on the right side: $\ce{2I2- <=> I- + I3-}$

Comment: It seems like [it does](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.475110) (+refs 1-7 therein).

Answer (score 6):

I found a [paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jp0671087)$\ce{^{[1]}}$ regarding the formation of diiodide anion species($\ce{I2^-}$). It is assumed to be an unstable species which forms during the formation of triiodide anion (excess of iodide in solution which makes it brown). This is a part of the paper which describes the formation of the species. For more information, read the full paper. Also, you can check the abstract which @andselisk linked.

> The $\ce{I2^-}$ species is formed by the 248-nm laser photolysis of
> iodide through the following reactions:
>
> $$\ce{I- + hν -> I + e_s-}$$
>
> $$\ce{I + I- ->[k2]I2^-}$$
>
> $$\ce{I2- + I2- ->[k3]I3- + I-}$$
>
> As discussed later, we found that photodetachment of electrons from
> $\ce{I-}$ ions produces solvated electrons ($\ce{e_s-}$) in ionic
> liquids as well as in molecular solvents. After photodetachment,
> iodine atoms react with $\ce{I-}$ to form diiodide anion radicals. In
> aqueous solution, the transient absorption maxima of $\ce{I2-}$ are
> located around 400 and 720 nm. The extinction coefficients of
> $\ce{I2-}$ in aqueous solution at 385 and 725 nm are 10000 and 2560
> M-1cm-1, respectively.[...]

$\ce{^{[1]}}$: J. Phys. Chem. B, **2007**, 111 (18), pp 4807–4811